# "Best" way for Android Arduino communication via ethernet

Tags: android, arduino, communication

I have an Arduino and an Android app which are communicating to each other via ethernet. The arduino shows a very simple webpage with only some values and an ID as seen below.

```
$1$201 //Value 1 ($1$): Temperature 20.1 degrees 
$2$66  //Value 1 ($2$): Humidity 66% 
$2$1   //Value 2 ($2$): Heating relay is on (1) 
etc. up to 50 values
```

The Android app will read the data from this webpage as a string using a HTTP get request, filters the data and shows the values on a custom made screen. It is also possible to send some data to the arduino to change some settings or switch a relay or something. You can see is as some kind of thermostat. So far so good.

The "problem" is that I need to manualy update the data using a button. The question is: How can I update my values automatically?

I was thinking to just send a httpRequest every few seconds (polling), but I'm not sure if this is the way to go because it seems to use of lot of data.

Who can advise me what would be a good solution?

Regards,

Bas

Answer (score 0):

The 'best' choice here will depend on your goals. Polling is easy to implement on the client (android) side. You could experiment with the optimal polling time depending on how 'fresh' your data needs to be compared to how much data you want your app to use. Alternatively, you could find or implement an http socket server such as [ArduinoWebsocketServer](https://github.com/ejeklint/ArduinoWebsocketServer), keeping in mind that the processor in your Arduino may or may not have the power needed to run this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My goal is to update the data every 5 seconds when my app is open. At this time a manually update a t maximum 50 times a day, and my mobile data usage is more than 10MB a month. even when the raw data is less than 0.5 kb...I have the feeling polling is maybe not the way to go. By the way...is it normal that a http request uses so much data or could there be something else wrong? Regards

Comment: Can you post the html response that your arduino serves up so we can look at optimizations? Perhaps rather than having the arduino serve up an entire web page it could serve up a small json blob and have the client render that.